# JavaScript convert string to date time

Tags: javascript, datetime, casting

I have a string that contains a datetime in the following format

```
2016-07-30 00:00:01.0310000
```

I need to convert this to a datetime object in JavaScript retaining the sub-seconds.

If I use

```
var d = new Date('2016-07-30 00:00:01.0310000');
```

Everything after 01 is dropped, how can I efficiently achieve this?

Comment: You could use a library like moment JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to parse the string yourself (which is quite simple, the only tricky bit is trailing zeros on the milliseconds value) and build the date using the `Date(years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)` constructor. Or use a library and a format string.

Here's an example:

```js
var str = "2016-07-30 00:00:01.0310000";
var parts = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+)\s*$/.exec(str);
var dt = !parts ? null : new Date(
    +parts[1],                   // Years
    +parts[2] - 1,               // Months (note we start with 0)
    +parts[3],                   // Days
    +parts[4],                   // Hours
    +parts[5],                   // Minutes
    +parts[6],                   // Seconds
    +parts[7].replace(/0+$/, '') // Milliseconds, dropping trailing 0's
);
if (dt.toISOString) {
  console.log(dt.toISOString());
} else {
  console.log("date", dt.toString());
  console.log("milliseconds", dt.getMilliseconds());
}
```

In the regex, `\d` means "a digit" and `{x}` means "repeated x times".

The `!parts ? null : new Date(...)` bit is so that if the string doesn't match the format, we get `null` rather than an error.

Comment: Thank you!  When attempting to run your code snippit locally I'm getting an error that toISOString() is not a method

Comment: @user316114: Tsk, you need to update your browser. :-) I'll change it to handle older browsers without `toISOString`.

Comment: Perfect, toGMTString() worked!  Unfortunately I cannot update my "browser".  My hands are tied as I'm working with a plugin that uses Rhino.  What I'm working on is preparing some data for the presentation layer in the user agent later on, so I'm stuck with what I'm working with.

Comment: @user316114: Actually I went a different way because `toGMTString` (on my browser) doesn't show milliseconds. But in any case, glad the parsing worked. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The milliseconds are saved (31), but what comes after that is not saved, because javascript does not support it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use library like Moment JS, You can read more http://momentjs.com/docs/

```
var day = moment("2016-07-30 00:00:01.0310000");

console.log(day._d); // Sat Jul 30 2016 00:00:01 GMT+0100 (WAT)
```